# Generar código de un paciente

Tags: c

Estoy realizando pruebas para un programa mayor y en este caso introduzco los datos de un paciente, que son guardados posteriormente en un `struct` e intento generar el código del paciente asociado que debe tener este formato (`<Inicial del 1er apellido><Inicial del 2º apellido><día><mes><año><valor aleatorio entre 1-700>`),
pero falla y no encuentro el error. Un ejemplo de código sería este: `GM141017650`

El programa en sí, si que compila pero se queda pillado al llegar a la invocación del subprograma `generarcodigo`.

Tal como indicó, el paso del `struct` es por referencia ya que me permite modificar el campo `codigo` de paciente mediante el código generado en el propio subprograma, realizado todo dentro del mismo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct{
  int dia;
  int mes;
  int anio;
}t_RegFecha;

typedef struct{
 char calle[20];
 int numcalle;
 char localidad[30];
 int codigopostal;
 char ciudad[30];
}t_RegDomicilio;


typedef struct{
 char codigo[20];
 char Nombre[15];
 char Apellido1[15];
 char Apellido2[15];
 char DNI[10];
 t_RegFecha FechaNacimiento;
 t_RegDomicilio Dom;
 t_RegFecha FechaAlta;
 t_RegFecha FechaBaja;
}t_RegPaciente;

typedef struct{
 char Nombre[15];
 char Apellido1[15];
 char Apellido2[15];
 char DNI[10];
 int numcolegiado;
 char Especialidad[30];
 t_RegDomicilio DireccionConsulta;
 int TelefonoConsulta;
 int ultimafactura;
}t_RegDatosDoctor;

void generarcodigo(t_RegPaciente *punt);


int main()
{
t_RegPaciente Paciente;

fflush(stdin);
printf("\nDatos del paciente...");
printf("\nNombre:");
gets(Paciente.Nombre);
printf("\nPrimer apellido:");
gets(Paciente.Apellido1);
printf("\nSegundo apellido:");
gets(Paciente.Apellido2);
printf("\nDNI:");
gets(Paciente.DNI);
printf("\nFecha de nacimiento(Día Mes Anio):");
scanf("%d %d %d",&Paciente.FechaNacimiento.dia,&Paciente.FechaNacimiento.mes,&Paciente.FechaNacimiento.anio);
fflush(stdin);
printf("\nDomicilio del paciente...");
printf("\n\tCalle:");
gets(Paciente.Dom.calle);
printf("\n\tNúmero de calle:");
scanf("%d",&Paciente.Dom.numcalle);
fflush(stdin);
printf("\n\tLocalidad:");
gets(Paciente.Dom.localidad);
printf("\n\tCódigo Postal:");
scanf("%d",&Paciente.Dom.codigopostal);
fflush(stdin);
printf("\n\tCiudad:");
gets(Paciente.Dom.ciudad);
printf("\nFecha de alta del paciente (Dia Mes Anio):");
scanf("%d %d %d",&Paciente.FechaAlta.dia,&Paciente.FechaAlta.mes,&Paciente.FechaAlta.anio);
fflush(stdin);
generarcodigo(&Paciente);

return 0;
}


void generarcodigo(t_RegPaciente *punt){
  int random;
  char aux[5];
  char codigo[15];

  strcat(codigo,punt->Apellido1[0]);
  strcat(codigo,punt->Apellido2[0]);
  itoa(punt->FechaNacimiento.dia,aux,10);
  strcat(codigo,aux);
  itoa(punt->FechaNacimiento.mes,aux,10);
  strcat(codigo,aux);
  itoa(punt->FechaNacimiento.anio,aux,10);
  strcat(codigo,aux);
  random=rand()%700+1;
  itoa(random,aux,10);
  strcat(codigo,aux);
  strcpy(punt->codigo,codigo);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede que si simplificas un poco el código de esta manera sera mas fácil detectar el problema, espero ayude. Las fechas son lo que veo que podrían dar problema, las defines como un entero porque la función itoa() es para convertir los datos enteros a cadena, lo cual no es necesario ya que la función gets() "ya" las toma como una cadena. Luego de esto la función strtok(), rompe la cadena en trozos, que puede ayudarte a hacer el codigo. Animo Dr.!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
 char codigo[20];
 char Nombre[15] = "Winnie";
 char Apellido1[15] = "De";
 char Apellido2[15] = "Pu";
 char DNI[10];
 t_RegFecha FechaNacimiento = "12051993";
 t_RegDomicilio Dom = "Bosque de los 100 acres";
 t_RegFecha FechaAlta = "12052011";
 t_RegFecha FechaBaja; = "12052019";
}t_RegPaciente;

void generarcodigo(t_RegPaciente *punt){
  int random;
  char aux[5];
  char codigo[15];

  strcat(codigo,punt->Apellido1[0]);
  strcat(codigo,punt->Apellido2[0]);
  itoa(punt->FechaNacimiento.dia,aux,10);
  strcat(codigo,aux);
  itoa(punt->FechaNacimiento.mes,aux,10);
  strcat(codigo,aux);
  itoa(punt->FechaNacimiento.anio,aux,10);
  strcat(codigo,aux);
  random=rand()%700+1;
  itoa(random,aux,10);
  strcat(codigo,aux);
  strcpy(punt->codigo,codigo);
  return codigo;
}
main()
{
  t_RegPaciente paciente;
  generarcodigo(&paciente);
  print("El codigo de paciente es: ", paciente);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Algunos alcances con respecto del codigo:

1.- Concatenación de strings (a arreglos de tipo char)

```
char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src)
```

la implementación de la fución `strcat` indica que deben ser 2 punteros a char, o en su defecto, arreglos del tipo char, por lo tanto la instrucción `strcat(codigo,punt->Apellido1[0])` no aplica, puesto que `Apellido1[0]` es un `char`. Si tu intención es utilizar un secuencia de funciones strcat para conformar tu codigo, te sugiero, ya que has definido una variable `aux` de tipo `char[5]`, usarla para extrae el primer caracter de los apellidos y luego concatenar. La idea es cambiar:

```
strcat(codigo,punt->Apellido1[0]);
```

a por el siguiente set de instrucciones:

```
memset(aux,0x0,sizeof(aux));
strncpy(aux, &punt->Apellido1[0],1);
strcat(codigo,aux);
```

`memset` es usado para inicializar la variable.

2.- Transformar de un numerico (int) a un string (char).

La función `itoa` no es una implementación standard, te sugiero utilizar la funcion `sprintf` de la biblioteca `stdio.h`, para formatear un texto con valores, para el caso enteros.

```
int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...)
```

Para la situación, te sugiero cambiar lo implementado:

```
itoa(punt->FechaNacimiento.dia,aux,10);
strcat(codigo,aux);
```

a por las siguientes lineas:

```
sprintf(aux,"%d",punt->FechaNacimiento.dia);
strcat(codigo,aux);
```

Espero te sirvan las sugerencias.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias  me ha servido como solución y ya va todo perfecto

Answer (score 0):

Usa [`sprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

```
//           Inicial apellido 1
//          /    Inicial apellido 2
//          |   /    Día
//          |   |   /    Mes
//          |   |   |   /    Año
//          |   |   |   |   /    Número de 3 dígitos
//          |   |   |   |   |   /    final de cadena
//          |   |   |   |   |   |   /   
//          v   v   v   v   v   v   v
char codigo[1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 1] = "";

//                Inicial apellido 1
//               /  Inicial apellido 2
//               | /  Día
//               | | /    Mes
//               | | |   /    Año
//               | | |   |   /    Número de 3 dígitos
//               | | |   |   |   /
//               v v v   v   v   v
sprintf(codigo, "%c%c%02d%02d%02d%03d",
                 *punt->Apellido1,
                   *punt->Apellido2, 
                     punt->FechaNacimiento.dia % 100,
                         punt->FechaNacimiento.mes % 100,
                             punt->FechaNacimiento.anio % 100,
                                 rand() % 700);
```